# How to obtain JavaBean informations at runtime with new API (Java 9)?

Tags: java, swing, javabeans, java-9, java-platform-module-system

I develop a library ([JAXX](https://gitlab.com/ultreiaio/jaxx)) to generate Swing java file using JavaBean information of Swing widgets, that I am trying to migrate to Java > 9 ([See issue](https://gitlab.com/ultreiaio/jaxx/issues/709)).

Using new JavaBean API does not work any longer, since I was using runtime reflection to get information from beans (See [JAXXIntrospector class](https://gitlab.com/ultreiaio/jaxx/blob/develop/jaxx-compiler/src/main/java/org/nuiton/jaxx/compiler/beans/JAXXIntrospector.java#L51)).

```
private static BeanInfo getExplicitBeanInfo(ClassDescriptor classDescriptor) {
    try {
        Class<?> beanClass = Class.forName(classDescriptor.getName(), true, classDescriptor.getClassLoader()); // see if there is a class by that name in this package
        Method findExplicitBeanInfo = Introspector.class.getDeclaredMethod("findExplicitBeanInfo", Class.class);
        findExplicitBeanInfo.setAccessible(true);
        return (BeanInfo) findExplicitBeanInfo.invoke(null, beanClass);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoClassDefFoundError e) {
        return null; // happens for uncompiled classes
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error: could not find method 'findExplicitBeanInfo' in java.beans.Introspector.  You are most likely running a version of Java against which JAXX has not been tested.");
    } catch (InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

I try to find how to get now thoses information using Jigsaw but could not find anywhere to to do this with the new API.

How can I get those runtime information now ?

Thanks.

Comment: JAXXIntrospector is hardly a reflection related component

Comment: Even after looking at your entire class, I’m not clear why you can’t use the regular [Introspector.getBeanInfo](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/beans/Introspector.html#getBeanInfo%28java.lang.Class,java.lang.Class%29) method.

Comment: I don't remember why it was done like this (I will try to use the normal method to see what's is going on with it).

Comment: It looks like you are hacking into a private method in java.beans.Introspector. That is very fragile and could break at any time. I assume it works in JDK 9/10/11 as it did before but you are getting a warning, is that right? As regards replacing it then core reflection has not changed so you should be able ot introspect without needing to hack into this internals of Introspector.

Comment: @AlanBateman, I got the code as it from the project (ten years ago!), and I never change it, since now... After some tests, it seems that using the public API works fine :) I imagine that the original developer wanted to get exactly the same behaviour reproducing exaclty what was done in Introspector class. I don't have that need, so my fix is ok to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the public API ([Introspector.getBeanInfo](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/beans/Introspector.html#getBeanInfo%28java.lang.Class,java.lang.Class%29)) solve the problem.